# Work of 2 functions

Tags: haskell

I am converting number from octal to decimal. I get number as `[Char]`, so I decided to convert it to `[Int]` first, then I multiply every digit by the corresponding power of 8. Finally, I planned to use `sum` and get my decimal number. How can I make 2 functions work one by one?

```
import Data.Char

charToDigit :: [Char] -> [Int] -- "123" -> [1,2,3]
charToDigit [] = []
charToDigit (x:xs) = digitToInt x : charToDigit xs

digitToDec :: [Int] -> [Int] -- [1,2,3] -> [64,16,3]
digitToDec [] = []
digitToDec (x:xs) = x * 8^(length xs) : digitToDec xs

octToDec :: [Char] -> Int
octToDec (x:xs) = charToDigit (x:xs) >>= digitToDec (x:xs) >>= sum (x:xs) -- "123" -> [1,2,3] -> [64,16,3] -> 64+16+3 = 83
```

Comment: Use the `(.)` operator: `octToDec = sum . digitToDec . charToDigit`. But your approach is rather inefficient.

Comment: Just a very minor observation: I find the name `octToDec` a bit misleading. IT does take octal digits for input, so the `octTo...` part is good. It does not produce decimal digits, or digits in any base: it produces the `Int` value itself, which is not related to `...Dec` in any way. Perhaps `octToInt`, `parseOct`, `octToValue` could be more appropriate.

Comment: Or if you were to write it the more obvious way - `octToDec x = sum (digitToDec (charToDigit x)))`

Answer (score 3):

Use the normal function composition operator `(.)` to compose functions:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

`>>=` is the monadic bind operator:

```
(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The solution to your question is simply:

```
octToDec = sum . digitToDec . charToDigit
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for practicing purposes another way to implement this functionality could be;

```
digits :: String -> [Int]
digits n | n == "" || n == "0" = []
         | otherwise           = ((++) <$> digits . show . (`div` 10) <*> return . (`rem` 10)) . read $ n

oct2dec :: String -> Int
oct2dec s = snd . foldr (\d r -> (1 + (fst r), snd r  + d * 8^(fst r))) (0,0) $ digits s

*Main> oct2dec "123"
83
```